# Date format without time in ASP.NET Gridview

Tags: c#

in ASP.NET gridview binding two dates. I want to display `dd/MM/yyyy` but it displays `10/03/2014 00:00:00`.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Fromdate" >
   <ItemTemplate >
   <asp:Label ID="lblFromDate" runat="server" 
              DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" 
              HtmlEncode="false"  
              Text='<%# Eval("Fromdate") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`DataFormatString` is a property of `BoundField` control and doesn't affect any other control. You can specify the format in an `Eval` expression:

```
Text='<%# Eval("Fromdate", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>' />
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47358604/why-is-gridview-column-not-sorted-as-date I am doing that but it's not sorting correctly.

Answer (score 20):

According to [**this article on MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the DataFormatString attribute has a limited number of variants for DateTime data.

What you are looking for is:

```
DataFormatString="{0:d}"
```

which is the `short date pattern`.

In order to get the `dd/MM/yyyy` format, you need to also set your culture info properly (for example to `**en-GB**`).

Comment: If you are editing that cell, the format gets changed to original format. To prevent it, add ApplyFormatInEditMode="true" along with DataFormatString="{0:d}"

Answer (score 8):

I achieved it with `{0:dd/MM/yyyy}` on the `DataFormatString` property of the field

It works well

Answer (score 4):

`DataFormatString` is a property of `BoundField` control and doesn't affect any other control. You can specify the format right in the `Eval` expression:

```
Text='<%# Eval("Fromdate", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>' />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fromdate">    
     <ItemTemplate>    
           <asp:Label ID="lblFromdate" runat="server"
                 Text='<%#Eval("Fromdate", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

Blockquote

Eval("Date","{0:dd-MM-yyyy}") %>' />