# custom date format in data grid view

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, date, datagridview

when I fetch data from database in datagridview ,then the date in date column shows for eg. 2/1/2020 12:00:00 AM, I want it to be shown only in "MM/yyyy" format. I tried

```
dataGridView1.Columns["P_exp_date"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
```

but it is showing like this (`2/1/2020 12:00:00 AM`) only.this line worked in my other forms of project but not working in this I don't know why..

I want to show only month and year part so it should be like

```
dataGridView1.Columns["P_exp_date"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM/yyyy";
```

but none of above is working. please help.

this is my code

```
private void LoadData(string P_id)
        {try{
            mode = FormMode.EditMode; //by editmode

            DataTable dt = DataBase.getDataTable("SELECT * FROM PRO_BILL INNER JOIN PRO ON PRO.P_id=PRO_BILL.P_id WHERE PRO_BILL.P_id=" + P_id + "");

            dataGridView1.Columns["P_exp_date"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)

            {
                int i = 0;
                i = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = dr["P_name"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["P_pack"].Value = dr["P_pack"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["P_comp"].Value = dr["P_comp"];
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["P_batch_no"].Value = dr["P_batchno"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["P_exp_date"].Value = dr["P_expdate"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["P_qty"].Value = dr["P_qty"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["P_free"].Value = dr["P_free"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["P_rate"].Value = dr["P_rate"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["P_mrp"].Value = dr["P_mrp"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["P_min_stock"].Value = dr["P_min_stk"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["P_max_stock"].Value = dr["P_max_stk"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["P_vat"].Value = dr["P_vat"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["P_total"].Value = dr["P_total"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["P_tabs"].Value = dr["P_tabs"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["P_sh"].Value = dr["P_sh"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Pro_id"].Value = dr["Pro_id"].ToString();
                tbSupname.Text = dr["P_sname"].ToString();
                tbBILLNO.Text = dr["P_billno"].ToString();
                tbCHLNno.Text = dr["P_chno"].ToString();
                dateTimePicker1.Text = dr["P_purdate"].ToString();
                tbtot1.Text = dr["P_ttotal"].ToString();
                tbTOtvat.Text = dr["P_vatto"].ToString();
                tbDisTOT.Text = dr["P_totdis"].ToString();
                tbGT.Text = dr["P_gt"].ToString();
                tbPID.Text = dr["P_id"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["tabsNofree"].Value = dr["tabsNofree"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Shelf_id"].Value = dr["Shelf_id"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["P_tabs"].Value = dr["P_tabs"].ToString();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["P_otabs"].Value = dr["P_otabs"].ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
        }
```

Comment: You can try when assigning  value using `.ToString("yourformat")`

Comment: @CoderofCode do you mean like this dr["P_expdate"].ToString("MM/yyyy");     ?

Comment: hi you can take help from this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22449788/date-format-without-time-in-asp-net-gridview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it like, Convert your data to DateTime and then apply the `ToString`with your format.

```
  dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["P_exp_date"].Value = (DateTime.Parse(dr["P_expdate"].ToString())).ToString("MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: this is showing folowwing Error 
1)The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments Argument 1: 
2)cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'

Comment: Did you add the `.ToString ` on `dr["P_expdate"].ToString()`