# how to merge cell datetime in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have one column in gridview which appear date and time. but i want to merge the column based on same date only although the time is not same. how to accomplish that ? this code and output i try so far and only merge other column instead column datetime.

```
  public void GridView_Row_Merger(GridView gridView)
{
    for (int rowIndex = gridView.Rows.Count - 2; rowIndex >= 0; rowIndex--)
    {
        GridViewRow currentRow = gridView.Rows[rowIndex];
        GridViewRow previousRow = gridView.Rows[rowIndex + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < currentRow.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            if (currentRow.Cells[i].Text == previousRow.Cells[i].Text)
            {
                if (previousRow.Cells[i].RowSpan < 2)
                    currentRow.Cells[i].RowSpan = 2;
                else
                    currentRow.Cells[i].RowSpan = previousRow.Cells[i].RowSpan + 1;
                previousRow.Cells[i].Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Assume you have 3 rows, A,B,C. If A & B's datetime column have the same date but different time, you want to hide row A, is that correct? Is the time part actually matter? Is it ok to show row B with the time part reset to 12:00 AM, or just show the date part?

Comment: no, if in a column have same date, it will merge to one. the time is not matter. i want to merge cell with same date. but this code not work because my time different although it same date. how to remove time from the date so that it can read and merge the cell without considering time. only consider date ?

Comment: @Martheen yes, sorry i just read back and what your understanding is ture ! no i dont want to consider time. only date. this code above consider time, thats why it is not merge the cell. no need show time, only date in row B. can you help me ?

Comment: Set your GridView to only display the [Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22449788/date-format-without-time-in-asp-net-gridview)

Comment: how to set that ? can you give me example ? @Martheen

Comment: The link should contain enough example

Comment: You are simply comparing the “strings” that apparently represent “Date” AND “Time” with the line: `if (currentRow.Cells[i].Text == previousRow.Cells[i].Text)`… If the text is in a valid `DateTime` format, you could simply create two `DataTime` objects from the strings and compare the dates only, i.e. year, month and day. Otherwise, if the strings are formatted in a similar fashion, then simply strip off the “time” portion of the strings then compare them. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just get an answer already ! this is the code. thanks guys for your help !

```
 public void GridView_Row_Merger(GridView gridView)
{
    for (int rowIndex = gridView.Rows.Count - 2; rowIndex >= 0; rowIndex--)
    {
        GridViewRow currentRow = gridView.Rows[rowIndex];
        GridViewRow previousRow = gridView.Rows[rowIndex + 1];
        string[] arra1 = currentRow.Cells[0].Text.Split(' ');
        string[] arra2 = previousRow.Cells[0].Text.Split(' ');
        currentRow.Cells[0].Text = arra1[0];
        previousRow.Cells[0].Text = arra2[0];
        if (currentRow.Cells[0].Text == previousRow.Cells[0].Text)
        {
            if (previousRow.Cells[0].RowSpan < 2)
            {
                currentRow.Cells[0].RowSpan = 2;
            }
            else
            {
                currentRow.Cells[0].RowSpan = previousRow.Cells[0].RowSpan + 1;
            }
            previousRow.Cells[0].Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```